# There is no sln file in proj.win32

Tags: cocos2d-x

I just installed cocos2d-x and created a new project using this command line : cocos new ProjectName -l cpp. It created with no errors but when i check proj.win32 folder, there was no .sln file. How can I open up this project? Or why there is no sln file?

Here is what proj.win32 folder looks like:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it correctly. There is no .sln file just from creating a new project.

Since you want .sln file, it means you want to use an IDE. As noted in https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x#using-ide, cmake is required in order to use IDE.

If you don't have cmake installed, download it from https://cmake.org/download/

After you have it installed, go to the proj.win32:

```
cd ProjectName/proj.win32
```

Then, run the following command:

```
cmake ..
```

The .sln file should be created.